# jQuery function won't rebind after first ajax call

Tags: jquery

I have a registration modal on my website that loads a captcha image (http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/108964/). If a user submits a wrong captcha the captcha image refreshes with a new image so that they can try again, but the code doesn't run a second, third, fourth, etc.. time. The image only refreshes once.

```
                    if(typeof(res.error) != "undefined") {
                        $('#loading_register_success').hide();
                        switch(res.error) {
                            case "already_registered":
                            default:
                                $('#register_submit').show();
                                $('.register_tab').hide();
                                $('.register_tab:first').show();
                                $.validationEngine.buildPrompt('#email','<?=l("already_registered_question") . " " . l("email")?>','error');
                            break;

                            case "captcha_mismatch":
                                if(res.refresh_captcha) {
                                    refreshCaptcha();
                                }

                                $('#register_submit').show();
                                $('#securimage_error').html(res.message).show();
                            break;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if(res.refresh_captcha) {
                            refreshCaptcha();
                            $('#register_submit').show();
                        } 
                            else
                                $.jGrowl(res.message, { life: 3000});

                        $("#loading_register_success").hide();
                    }
```

**Refresh Captcha Function:**

```
var refreshCaptcha = function() {
    var captcha = $('#captcha_holder').find('img');
    $('#loader').show();
    captcha.hide();
    $('#loader').hide();
    captcha.attr('src', '');
    captcha.attr('src', '/<?=$this->session->userdata("cur_lang")?>/register/secur_image');
    captcha.show();
}
```

The trigger to start all of this is when someone clicks on the submit button in the form. There is a .live('click') event bound to this button...

Any ideas why this won't run?

**EDIT::**
So it appears that in FF the new image appears, but it quickly swaps it out with a new image. But when submitting a wrong captcha it does nothing. Doesn't want to swap the image out. I am so lost.

Comment: i've never seen someone put more cases after the default case in a switch statement. does that work?

Comment: Yeah it works, or at least I've never had an issue with it. I typically don't write my switch statements like that, I wrote it pretty fast the first go around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out my issue. I needed to add in a "cache buster" to the random image generator.

**Working Code:**

```
var refreshCaptcha = function() {
    $('#captcha_holder').html('');

    $('#loader').show("fast", function(){
        $('#captcha_holder').delay(3000).find('img:first').remove();
        $('#captcha_holder').append('<img id="securimage_img" />');
        $('#captcha_holder').find('img:first').attr('src', '/<?=$this->session->userdata("cur_lang")?>/register/secur_image/' + Math.random() + '');
        $(this).hide();
    });

    return false;
}
```